# How can I set up my Mysql server that can be accessed from other machines in the same network?

Tags: mysql

I have a situation, my local machine Mysql server should be accessed using my machine name or IP address. (Not only with 'localhost')

I have googled it, but I am able to find only below information but that did not worked

adding entries in my.cnf file

```
bind-address    = 127.0.0.1
```

commenting

```
skip-networking
```

Please help.

Comment: When you try to connect from another machine using mysql (mysql -h <IP> ) what is the error you are getting?

Comment: I guess bind-address should be 0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1

Comment: "ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '10.254.64.83' (10061)"

Answer (score 0):

```
0.0.0.0 instead of 127.0.0.1
```

This solution worked. Thanks to @ahmad. Up-vote to him.